# Maximum Likelihood Estimation for Normal Distribution with parameters $\theta$ and $2\theta$ with $\theta>0$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I'm using log-likelihood and eventually I get to the following quadratic equation: $n{\theta}^{2} + 2n\theta - \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2 = 0$. After solving the equation I get a solution ($\frac{-n + \sqrt{n^2 + n\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}}{n}$) that seems rather cumbersome and it's hard to check weather the given solution is indeed a maximum of the log-likelihood function. Is the solution correct and there simply isn't an easier way to do it or am I missing something here?

Comment: It would be natural to divide through by $n$ so ${\theta}^{2} + 2\theta - \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2 = 0$ and $\sqrt{1+\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}-1$

Comment: It's not surprising to see some kind of peculiar thing because the mean and variance are coupled, so $\theta_{MLE}$ is somehow a weighted average of the sample mean and half the sample standard deviation (I assume you use the $N(\mu,\sigma)$ convention not the $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ convention). The weights being nonlinear is not a surprise.

Comment: Actually it's $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, that's at least the one we've been using in our classes. The book might actually be using the other one, I'll need to check this

Comment: If it is the variance then something is definitely fishy about the scaling in your formula for $\theta_{MLE}$. (Something is also fishy about the model formulation in this case because then $2$ actually has units, which would be a very strange way to do things.)

Comment: What was your expression for the log-likelihood?

Comment: $\frac{-n}{2}ln(4\pi\theta) - \frac{1}{4\theta}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \theta)^2$

Comment: Did you mean the variance is $2\theta,$ or the standard deviation is $2\theta \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: BTW standard notation is $\ln(4\pi\theta),$ not $ln(4\pi\theta). \qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud inspect your log-likelihood function (which you should include in the question):

$$\ell(\theta)=-\frac{n}{2}\log (4\pi\theta) - \frac{1}{4\theta}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \theta)^2$$

Its (natural [*]) domain is $(0,+\infty)$. The function is continuous and differentiable in all its domain. The behaviour at the extremes is: $$\lim_{\theta \to 0^+}\ell(\theta)=-\infty$$ (the second term wins) and $$\lim_{\theta \to +\infty}\ell(\theta)=-\infty$$

You've found a single critical point, inside the domain. Then, it must be a local maximum, and also a global maximum.

The fact that the critical point is a local maximum can also be seen by computing the second derivative.

---

[*] It should be stressed that the domain of the parameter should be part of the likelihood definition (as with any function). I'm just assuming here the "natural" one (the largest subset of the reals), but if your problem statement somehow implies a more restricted domain, the answer could differ.

Comment: This seems correct. Thank you!

Comment: Using a capital $L$ rather than a lower-case $\ell$ for the log-likelihood seems a bit like letting $n$ approach $0$ as $\varepsilon$ approahces $\infty. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Haha, you're right, (nobody has ever seen an $\epsilon$ approaching $\infty$!). Fixing

Answer (score 1):

$$
L(\theta) \propto \frac 1 {\sqrt\theta^n} \exp\left( \frac {-1}{2(2\theta)} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\theta)^2 \right) 
$$
Let $\overline x = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ and $s^2 = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n 
(x_i-\overline x)^2.$ Then algebra tells us that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\theta)^2 = ns^2 + n(\overline x - \theta)^2.
$$
Hence
$$
L(\theta) \propto \frac 1 {\sqrt\theta^n} \exp\left( \frac{-1}{4\theta} \left( ns^2 + n(\overline x -\theta)^2 \right) \right).
$$
\begin{align}
\ell(\theta) & = \log L(\theta) = \text{constant} - \frac n 2 \log\theta - \frac {ns^2} {4\theta} - \frac{n(\overline x-\theta)^2}{4\theta} \\[10pt]
& = \text{constant} - \frac n 2 \log\theta - \frac{ns^2}{4\theta} - \frac{n\overline x^2}{4\theta} + \text{constant} - \frac{n\theta} 4 \\[10pt]
\ell\,'(\theta) & = - \frac n {2\theta} + \frac{ns^2}{4\theta^2} +\frac{n\overline x^2}{4\theta^2} - \frac n 4 \\[10pt]
& = \frac {-n} {4\theta^2} \left( 2\theta - s^2 - \overline x^2 + \theta^2 \right). \\[10pt]
& = (\text{negative constant}) \cdot \left( (\theta+1)^2 -s^2-\overline x^2 - 1 \right) 
\end{align}
Since $\theta$ cannot be negative, the above expression is $0$ only if
$$
\theta = -1 +\sqrt{s^2+\overline x^2 + 1}.
$$